My code is not Dsiplaying my profile screen content to see my profile screen

This is my ViewModel



@HiltViewModel
class galBaatviewModel @Inject constructor(
    val auth: FirebaseAuth,
    var db : FirebaseFirestore,
    val storage : FirebaseStorage

) : ViewModel() {


    var inProcess = mutableStateOf(false)
    val eventMutableState = mutableStateOf<Event<String>?>(null)
    var signIn = mutableStateOf(false)
    val userData = mutableStateOf<UserData?>(null)
    init {

        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        signIn.value = currentUser!= null
        currentUser?.uid?.let {
            getUserData(it)
        }

    }


    fun signUp(name: String, number: String, email: String, Password: String) {
        inProcess.value = true
        if(name.isEmpty() or number.isEmpty() or email.isEmpty() or Password.isEmpty()){
            HandleException(customMessage = "Please fill all fields")
            return
        }
        inProcess.value = true
        db.collection(USER_NODE).whereEqualTo("number",number).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if(it.isEmpty){
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, Password).addOnCompleteListener {

                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        signIn.value = true
                        createOrUpdateProfile(name,number)
                    } else {
                        HandleException(it.exception, customMessage = "Sign Up failed")
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                HandleException(customMessage = "number already exist")
                inProcess.value = false
            }
        }

    }

    fun LogIn(email: String,Password: String){
        if(email.isEmpty() or Password.isEmpty()){
            HandleException(customMessage = "Please fill all the fields")
        }
        else{
            inProcess.value = true
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,Password).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    signIn.value = true
                    inProcess.value = false
                    auth.currentUser?.uid?.let {
                        getUserData(it)
                    }
                }else{
                    HandleException(exception = it.exception, customMessage = "Login failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun uploadProfileImage(uri : Uri){
            uploadImage(uri){
                createOrUpdateProfile(imageUrl = it.toString())
            }
    }

    fun uploadImage(uri: Uri,onSuccess: (Uri)->Unit){
        inProcess.value = true
        val storageRef = storage.reference
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
        val imageRef = storageRef.child("images/$uuid")
        val uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(uri)
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {
            val result = it.metadata?.reference?.downloadUrl
            result?.addOnSuccessListener(onSuccess)
                inProcess.value = false


        }
            .addOnFailureListener{
                HandleException(it)
            }
    }

    fun createOrUpdateProfile(name: String?=null,number: String?=null,imageUrl:String?=null){

        var uid=auth.currentUser?.uid
        val userData =UserData(
            userId = uid,
            name = name?:userData.value?.name,
            number = number?: userData.value?.number,
            imageUrl = imageUrl?: userData.value?.imageUrl
        )
        uid?.let{
            inProcess.value = true
            db.collection(USER_NODE).document(uid).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                if(it.exists()){
                    //update user data
                }
                else{
                    db.collection(USER_NODE).document(uid).set(userData)
                    inProcess.value = false
                    getUserData(uid )
                }
            }
                .addOnFailureListener{
                    HandleException(it, "cannot retrieve user")
                }

        }
    }

    private fun getUserData(uid: String) {
        inProcess.value = true
        db.collection(USER_NODE).document(uid).addSnapshotListener{
            value, error->
            if(error!= null){
                HandleException(error,"can not retrieve user")
            }
            if(value != null){
                var user = value.toObject<UserData>()
                userData.value = user
                inProcess.value = false
            }
        }
    }

    fun HandleException(exception: Exception? = null, customMessage: String = "") {
        Log.e("GalBaat", "GalBaat exception: ", exception)
        exception?.printStackTrace()
        val errorMsg = exception?.localizedMessage ?: ""
        val message = if (customMessage.isNullOrEmpty()) errorMsg else customMessage

        eventMutableState.value = Event(message)
        inProcess.value = false
    }
}




This is my ProfileScreen Code

package com.example.galbaat.screen



@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(navController: NavController,vm : galBaatviewModel) {
    val inProgress = vm.inProcess.value
    if(inProgress){
        CommonProgressBar()
    }else{
        Column {
            ProfileContent(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .padding(8.dp),
                vm =vm,
                name = "",
                number = "",
                onNameChange = {""},
                onNumberChange = {""},
                onSave = {},
                onBack = {},
                onLogOut ={}
            )
            BottomNavigationMenu(selectedItem = BottomNavigationItem.PROFILE, navController = navController)
        }

    }



}
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ProfileContent(

    vm: galBaatviewModel,
    name: String,
    number:String,
    onNameChange:(String)->Unit,
    onNumberChange:(String)->Unit,
    onBack : ()->Unit,
    onSave: ()-> Unit,
    onLogOut: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier,) {
    val imageUrl = vm.userData.value?.imageUrl
    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        ) {
            Text(text = "BACK", Modifier.clickable {
                onBack.invoke()
            })
            Text(text = "SAVE", Modifier.clickable {
                onSave.invoke()
            })
            CommonDivider()
            ProfileImage(imageUrl = imageUrl, vm = vm)

            CommonDivider()
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(4.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            )
            {
                Text(text = "Name", modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp))
                TextField(
                    value = name, onValueChange = onNameChange,
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        focusedTextColor = Color.Black,
                        containerColor = Color.Transparent

                    )
                )
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(4.dp), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            )
            {
                Text(text = "Number", modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp))
                TextField(
                    value = number, onValueChange = onNumberChange,
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        focusedTextColor = Color.Black,
                        containerColor = Color.Transparent
                    )
                )
            }
            CommonDivider()
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Text(text = "Logout", modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    onLogOut.invoke()
                })
            }
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun ProfileImage(imageUrl:String?,vm: galBaatviewModel){
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) {
            uri ->
        uri?.let {
            vm.uploadProfileImage(uri)
        }

    }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)){
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {
                launcher.launch("image/*")
            },
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Card(shape = CircleShape,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .size(100.dp)) {
                CommonImage(data = imageUrl)
            }
            Text(text = "Change Profile Picture")
        }
        if(vm.inProcess.value)
            CommonProgressBar()

    }
}


This my Main Activity

package com.example.galbaat




sealed class DestinationScreens(var route: String){
object SignUp : DestinationScreens("signup")
object Login : DestinationScreens("login")
object profile : DestinationScreens("ProfileScreen")
object ChatList : DestinationScreens("chatList")
object SingleChat : DestinationScreens("singleChat/{chatId}"){
    fun createRoute(id: String) = "SingleChat/$id"
}
    object StatusList : DestinationScreens("statusList")
object SingleStatus : DestinationScreens("singleStatus/{UserId}"){
    fun createRoute(Userid: String) = "SingleChat/$Userid"
}
}
@AndroidEntryPoint

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            GALBAATTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    chatAppNavigation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Composable
    fun chatAppNavigation(){
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        var vm = hiltViewModel<galBaatviewModel>()
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = DestinationScreens.SignUp.route){
            composable(DestinationScreens.SignUp.route){
                SignUp(navController,vm)
            }
            composable(DestinationScreens.Login.route){
                loginScreen(navController=navController,vm = vm)
            }
            composable(DestinationScreens.ChatList.route){
                chatScreen(navController = navController , vm = vm)
            }
            composable(DestinationScreens.StatusList.route){
                StatusScreen(navController = navController , vm = vm)
            }
            composable(DestinationScreens.profile.route){
                ProfileScreen(navController = navController , vm = vm)
            }

        }

    }
}


i tried to route it correctly but on my prfile its not showing anything i have attached my profile screen code along with my viewmodel code and main activity code it seems more of a function calling issue which im unable to resolve

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted more than 400 (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question.

im sorry im really a newbie it would be great if you can help

Please edit your question as requested in the first comment. In this way, you'll increase the chances of being helped.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
